# Create a new variable in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I am new to Tableau and trying to get myself oriented to this system. I am an R user and typically work with wide data formats, so getting things wrangled into the proper long format has been tricky.  Here is my current problem.

Assume I have a data file that is structured as such

```
ID       Disorder     Value
1         A             0     
1         B             1
1         C             0
2         A             1
2         B             1
2         C             1
3         A             0
3         B             0
3         C             0
```

What I would like to do is to combine the variables, such that the presence of a set of disorders are used for summary variables.  For example, how could I go about achieving something like this as my output?  The sum is the number of people with the disorder, and the percentage is the number of people with the disorder divided by the total number of people.

```
Disorders        Sum       Percentage
A                 1            33.3 
B                 2            66.6
C                 1            33.3
AB                2            66.6
BC                2            66.6
AC                1            33.3
ABC               2            66.6
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The approach to this would really be dependent on how flexible it has to be. Ultimately a wide data source with your Disorder making columns would make this easier. You will still need to blend the results on a data scaffold that has the combinations of codes you are wanting to get this to work in Tableau. If this needs to scale, you'll want to do the transformation work using custom SQL or another ETL tool like Alteryx. I posted a solution to this question for you over on the Tableau forum where I can upload files: http://community.tableausoftware.com/message/316168